# How can i print these 2 string, one in a line and the other on another?

Tags: python

I need to print string_a and string_b in 2 separate lines

I tried separating the print command in 2 lines but it doesn't work

```
print(string_a +
      string_b)
```

For my situation i cant just print 2 different things

```
print(string_a)
print(string_b)
```

this is basically what i need to do:

```
string_a = 'hello '
string_b = 'world'
print(string_a + string_b)
```

i want it to print:

```
'hello
world'
```

but it just prints:

```
'hello world'
```

Comment: ```print(string_a + '\n' + string_b)```

Comment: `print(f"'{string_a}\n{string_b}'")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add line breaks where you need to output line breaks, otherwise Python will not automatically line breaks

```
string_a = 'hello '
string_b = 'world'
print(string_a +'\n'+ string_b)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
string1 = 'hello'
string2 = 'world'
print(string1, string2, sep='\n')
```

output:

```
hello
world
```

And, if you want to print output in below format

```
'hello
 world' (with quotes)
```

then, try this:

```
print("'{}\n{}'".format(string1, string2))
```

Answer (score 1):

As no one suggested the python 3 f-strings way to do it, i will add another answer, as i think it is the better solution, as it is up to date, and should replace the old python string formatting as it's easier to read, and has faster run time then "".format, or % formatting.

```
string_a = 'hello'
string_b = 'world'
print(f'{string_a}\n{string_b}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Cramming a newline in the middle is probably the easiest:

```
print(string_a +"\n"+ string_b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [f string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) in python. I like this type of string because it is very useful and easy to read

```
string_a = 'hello '
string_b = 'world'
print(f'{string_a} \n{string_b}')
```

This will print:

```
hello
world
```

You can even put numbers in for variables in the `{}`, not just string types. Also, `\n` stands for newline, which prints to a new line

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `"""` to get your desire result:-

```
string_a = 'hello '
string_b = 'world'
string_c = 'bye'
print(f"""{string_a}  # To print anything on next line simplly go to the next line.
{string_b}
{string_c}""")
```

**OutPut**

```
hello 
world
bye
```